# Local database to every node in the network

Tags: private-blockchain

I'm developing blockchain based application related to the vehicle industry. Application will be running in a private network. As I know it is expensive to store lot of data on blockchain.

Is it possible to setup a local database to every node in the network and just save the hash of the data in transactions ? So they can easily access the data or check the validity of the data.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is your private network, it is technically possible for you to do anything. Your only limitations are your skills to develop software.

However your logic does not make sense. There is practically no cost of saving data in the private chain, or the cost would be equal expensive as running a database.